# Why isn't my data being put into the database?

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to put a users input into the database. The database connects fine but I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My `index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Encrypt</h1>
<form action="http://localhost/si/r.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="encrypt-in">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

And my `r.php`

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxx","s");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$password = $_POST['encrypt-in'];

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO pass (Password) VALUES ($password)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And don't worry its not really a password. Any ideas?

Comment: use single quote for string values in insert `'$password'`

Comment: This would solve the problen, tough he would still be open to SQL injection. He should also use prepared statements, which will also solve the problem.

Comment: I know. I'm just playing around with PHP at the moment. @enricog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO pass (Password) VALUES ('$password')");`

You may also want to surround your $_POST or use prepared statements.

`$password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['encrypt-in']);`

Comment: So the second example would be secure?

Comment: @user302975 from SQL injections, it should be.

Comment: What else would I have to worry about other then SQL injections?